# How important is a college degree for a programming job?

Tags: career-development, software-development

I am wondering how important a college degree is for a programming job ... By that I mean to what extent would it hurt me  not to have a college degree to eventually get hired for a programming job . If "programming job" is too vague , we can say C++ Jobs , or Node.js jobs , etc . . . ? Many people are telling me to extremely focus on education i just want to see your view in it Thankyou :)

Comment: I learned two things by visiting your GitHub: first, you're 15, and second... you program like a 15-year old. Take whatever opportunities you can to learn from others and grow -- you'll be happy you did.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill I Program like a 5 year old? Well Most Of My Projects as of now isnt professional

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill But i 100% Have the ability to write 100% Readble code .. Its just that i am more concerned on learning as of now

Comment: The point I want to make isn't that you don't have the potential to be a good coder -- you've put a lot of things together already for someone your age, and that's great -- but that there's a lot you haven't been exposed to yet that you'll learn about as you continue your education. There's a lot more to coding that just knowing the syntax of some languages. Programmers never stop learning, in fact -- there's always something new. All I'm saying is that although college might not be an absolute requirement, but without it, you'll need to develop more skills. Stay in school, learn what you can.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Learning Never Ends. 100% True fact there . The only advantage i see going to college is to Have More Social skills (Which i am totally not lacking :D ).

Comment: Depends where you are, if there are plenty of qualified people around then yes, if not, then no.

Comment: @amanuel2 A big part of what you learn at a university is learning "how to learn", which you will surely need in any case if you are a programmer. University is not the only way to get this skill, but then again, if you get a degree out of it...

Comment: @Brandin I think i already have the skill "how to learn" . I am learning about osdev every day

Comment: @amanuel2 That's just one thing you get. Not to mention you also get a degree if you finish. Even if you study perfectly on your own, you won't get that..

Comment: @Brandin One Thing? I also have perfectly studied web dev by myself

Comment: @Brandin And honestly osdev is an extremely big subject

Comment: @amanuel2 I meant one thing you get from going to university. Learning how to learn is one thing, getting a degree is another, ...

Comment: @Brandin Yea your right

Answer (score 1):

While theoretically you can learn all this stuff without matriculating , attending a highly regarded university provides some confidence that you have learned the principles  of how to do it right rather than just how to hack together something that works.

As a result, the degree is somewhere between being almost as good as a few years of  prior professional experience and better than those years of experience. It will get you considered for jobs that otherwise would discard your application unread, and a good program will give you skills that you may not need in the first assignment but that will be more valuable than you expect later on.

University is also an excellent opportunity to learn life skills, and some of those -- like learning how to deal with difficult personalities -- are also more valuable than you might realize. Independent or online study really does not provide that, and it may affect your ability to retain a job or to work with others to maximize your impact and value.

I understand the temptation to look for shortcuts and cost savings, especially given that tuition at some schools is fairly obscene unless you can qualify for student aid or scholarships or can find a good work/study opportunity that pays a reasonable wage. But as far as I can tell, it remains mostly  true that you get what you pay for.

Comment: Honestly i already have programming experience : github.com/amanuel2 . But my question is do i need college to have a job? Someone's(Anonymous Person) telling me that if I don't go to college 95% of the jobs won't hire me. Is that true?

Comment: @amanuel2 You need to focus less on what one person is saying to you. The simple fact is every hiring manager is different. I have a programming job with no formal experience, but I have 10 years technical experience with software in addition to several years self taught. I can tell from your responses you really aren't taking in what others are telling you, you want to hear what you already think is right. The simple fact is, you might get lucky, but you'll learn a lot more from a formal education and finish with something hiring managers favor over a few Github respositories.

Comment: 95% of which jobs? If you don't want to be anything more than a code monkey writing website scripts, or other grunt work, you may not need the degree. To do more interesting things sooner in your career, and earn more, you probably do.

Comment: Writing code is easy. Algorithms and data structures and architecture and robust multitasking and security and performance and.... are not. You're suffering from not knowing how much you don't know.

Comment: @Dandy I am taking what everyone is telling me an evaluating it. Github repo , is mainly to show your talent. I'm starting to get that every job is different they might require a degree or not.